# Mixed Erlang/Elixir projects - can I use mix or rebar?

Tags: build, erlang, rebar, elixir-mix, elixir

For Erlang code, I use **rebar**. For Elixir code, I use the built-in **mix** tool.

Now I want to have a mixed Erlang/Elixir project. Can I use **rebar** to compile **Elixir** code? Or can I use **mix** to compile **Erlang** code?

If so, how?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Mix can compile erlang files if you put them in `src`. There is a `rebar_elixir_plugin` to compile Elixir code from rebar but it is not as efficient at it as Mix.

Comment: Please, use a distinctive name for "Mix" build tool. It is hard to google it!

Comment: Mix ships with Elixir and can be found in Elixir source code. The tool linked above is a very old variant.

Comment: Yeah I know but still googling "mix" isn't the best thing to find resources.

Comment: // , We just need to link farm until elixir-lang and its tools are the top results for words like elixir and mix! Like what happens when the non-programmer muggles search for "python" and end up with some weird programming language.  FTW.